# How to extract all the .tgz files from directory

Tags: extract, tar, gunzip

I have a directory

`directory/subdir1/temp1.tgz
          /subdir2/temp2.tgz
          /subdir3/subdirectory1/temp3.tgz
          /subdir4/temp4.tgz`

How to extract all temp files using terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
find directory -name "*.tgz" -type f -exec tar xzf {} \;
```

This will extract all the files in current directory!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

z means (un)zip.

x means extract files from the archive.

v means print the filenames verbosely

f means the following argument is a filename.

The -exec option executes tar of the found file, and {} will be replaced by the tar file's name

```
find -name "*.tgz" -exec tar xvzf '{}' \;
```